# Disk Boot Failure after power outage

Tags: boot, boot-failure, disk

I recently experienced a power outage whilst logged on to 11.04 with XP running on VirtualBox.  When I now try to boot, I receive the `Disk Boot failure, Insert System disk and Press Enter`.

I have run a Disk utility and all seems fine.  I can boot from a live USB and browse the files on the drive.

`fdisk` returns the following:-

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320071851520 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0007cc25

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1         125      999424   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2             125         374     1999872   82  Linux swap / Solaris
Partition 2 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda3             374       38914   309569536   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 1048 MB, 1048576000 bytes
33 heads, 61 sectors/track, 1017 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 2013 * 512 = 1030656 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x20ac7dda

This doesn't look like a partition table
Probably you selected the wrong device.

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   ?     1601838     1816876   216435558+   7  HPFS/NTFS
Partition 1 has different physical/logical beginnings (non-Linux?):
     phys=(187, 180, 14) logical=(1601837, 17, 6)
Partition 1 has different physical/logical endings:
     phys=(784, 0, 13) logical=(1816875, 10, 55)
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sdb2   ?     1625446     2595868   976730017   16  Hidden FAT16
Partition 2 has different physical/logical beginnings (non-Linux?):
     phys=(906, 235, 61) logical=(1625445, 2, 35)
Partition 2 has different physical/logical endings:
     phys=(262, 116, 59) logical=(462252, 6, 37)
Partition 2 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sdb3   ?           1           1           0   6f  Unknown
Partition 3 has different physical/logical beginnings (non-Linux?):
     phys=(370, 101, 50) logical=(0, 0, 1)
Partition 3 has different physical/logical endings:
     phys=(10, 114, 13) logical=(2133615, 4, 57)
Partition 3 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sdb4           24939      484122   462167897    0  Empty
Partition 4 has different physical/logical beginnings (non-Linux?):
     phys=(0, 0, 0) logical=(24938, 6, 17)
Partition 4 has different physical/logical endings:
     phys=(0, 0, 0) logical=(484121, 13, 4)
Partition 4 does not end on cylinder boundary.

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you checked your system BIOS settings?